# setOnItemClickListener on Android App with custom Adapter not triggering

Tags: android, listview, onclick, adapter

I am trying to get a code segment to trigger when the user clicks on an item. It is triggering on the custom adapter but not on the main segment.

This is the code segment for the adapter and what I am trying to trigger but its not being triggered.

```
public class Program_Lure_list_Adapter extends BaseAdapter implements View.OnClickListener {


private static ArrayList<Program_Lure_Sound> programLureList;

private LayoutInflater l_inflater;

private int mPosition;

private int[] Image = {R.drawable.blacksound};
ViewHolder viewHolder;
ViewHolder selectedHolder;

private Activity activity;
public Program_Lure_list_Adapter(Activity a, ArrayList<Program_Lure_Sound> result) {
    activity = a;
    programLureList = result;
    l_inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.
            getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

}

/*public Program_Lure_list_Adapter(Context context, ArrayList<Program_Lure_Sound> result) {
    programLureList = result;
    l_inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

}*/

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return programLureList.size();
}

/*@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return null;
}*/

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

/*@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return 0;
}*/

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    if (view == null) {
        view = l_inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_programlure_listitem, viewGroup, false);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.iv_Image_souund = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView29);
        viewHolder.tv_soundName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView92);
        viewHolder.tv_selected = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView_selected);
        view.setTag(viewHolder);

    } else
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

    viewHolder.iv_Image_souund.setImageResource(Image[programLureList.get(i).getSoundImage()]);
    viewHolder.tv_soundName.setText(programLureList.get(i).getSoundName());
    viewHolder.tv_selected.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    view.setTag(viewHolder);
    view.setOnClickListener(this);
    return view;

}

@Override
public void onClick(final View v) {
    v.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            ViewHolder holder = ((ViewHolder) v.getTag());
            holder.tv_selected.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            if (selectedHolder != null)
                selectedHolder.tv_selected.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            selectedHolder = holder;
        }
    });

}
public class ViewHolder{
    TextView tv_soundName;
    ImageView iv_Image_souund;
    TextView tv_selected;
}

private class OnItemClickListener  implements OnClickListener{
    private int mPosition;

    OnItemClickListener(int position){
        mPosition = position;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        Activity_program_lure sct = (Activity_program_lure)activity;
        sct.onItemClick(mPosition);


    }
}
```

}

This is the custom adapter, the onClick is triggering properly but I need the other segment to trigger as well.

```
        if(getSoundList()!=null) {
        final ArrayList<Program_Lure_Sound> plsList = getSoundList();
        //mAdapter = new Program_Lure_list_Adapter(this, plsList);
        mAdapter = new Program_Lure_list_Adapter(Activity_program_lure.this, plsList);
        activeSoundList.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(activeSoundList);


        // activeSoundList.setAdapter();
        //  activeSoundList
        activeSoundList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                Log.v("BLEApp", "HEREHERE2");
                String name = plsList.get(i).getSoundName();

                String[] arr = name.split(" ");

                String ID = arr[0].split("#")[1];
                // soundCode = ID;
                //showToast("Sound code: "+soundCode);
                String sd = plsList.get(i).getSoundName();
                if (sd.length() > 10)
                    sd = sd.substring(0, Math.min(sd.length(), 10));
                tv_ActiveSound.setText(sd);
                if (mBluetoothLeService != null) {
                    // playSound(ID);
                    try {
                        changeToSound(ID);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else {
                    showToast("Please, click on power button and then click to" +
                            "play sound...!");
                }
            }
        });

        // endregion

        dbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);
        String lureUsed = dbHelper.LureUsed(lureName);
        dbHelper.closeDB();
        tv_LureUsed.setText(lureUsed);

    }

    float  opacity = 0.4f;
    ll.setAlpha(opacity);
    tv_power.setText("ON");
    playSoundButton.setAlpha(opacity);
    playSoundButton.setEnabled(false);


}

public void onItemClick(int mPosition) {
    Log.v("BLEApp", "HEREHERE");
    final ArrayList<Program_Lure_Sound> plsList = getSoundList();

    int i=mPosition; String name = plsList.get(i).getSoundName();

    String[] arr = name.split(" ");

    String ID = arr[0].split("#")[1];
    // soundCode = ID;
    //showToast("Sound code: "+soundCode);
    String sd = plsList.get(i).getSoundName();
    if(sd.length()>10)
        sd = sd.substring(0, Math.min(sd.length(),10));
    tv_ActiveSound.setText(sd);
    if(mBluetoothLeService!=null){
        // playSound(ID);
        try {
            changeToSound(ID);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else{
        showToast("Please, click on power button and then click to" +
                "play sound...!");
    }
}
```

Any ideas? I'm guessing it's something simple I'm missing.

Comment: How do I change it to not be the whole view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this in your main activity

```
mAdapter = new Program_Lure_list_Adapter(MainActivity.this, plsList);
```

then in your custom adapter class

```
private Activity activity;    
    public Program_Lure_list_Adapter(Activity a, ArrayList<Program_Lure_Sound> result) {
    activity = a;
            programLureList = result;
            l_inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.
                    getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        }
```

Implement this method in your custom adapter class which will tell your main activity or in your case your other segment activity to click which item.

```
private class OnItemClickListener  implements OnClickListener{
        private int mPosition;

        OnItemClickListener(int position){
            mPosition = position;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            MainActivity sct = (MainActivity)activity;
            sct.onItemClick(mPosition);


        }
    }
```

And modify these two methods too like following.

```
public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
```

After that put your other segment code in the main activity in the following method like this

public void onItemClick(int mPosition) {

int i=mPosition;
String name = plsList.get(i).getSoundName();

```
            String[] arr = name.split(" ");

            String ID = arr[0].split("#")[1];
           // soundCode = ID;
            //showToast("Sound code: "+soundCode);
            String sd = plsList.get(i).getSoundName();
            if(sd.length()>10)
            sd = sd.substring(0, Math.min(sd.length(),10));
            tv_ActiveSound.setText(sd);
            if(mBluetoothLeService!=null){
               // playSound(ID);
                try {
                    changeToSound(ID);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else{
                showToast("Please, click on power button and then click to" +
                        "play sound...!");
            }



}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I tried adding the top method to the custom adapter class but it just says "Cannot resolve symbol onClickListener"

Comment: OnClickListener ('O' capitalize) if that's the problem , check that .

Comment: import android.view.View.OnClickListener; try to import this and if it still stays provide some more information about the error.

Comment: That did resolve that error, but now activity is not being resolved in this: Activity_program_lure sct = (Activity_program_lure)activity;       Activity_program_lure is my main activity

Comment: this is your custom adapter activity or your main launching activity? what are the names of your two activity.

Comment: The custom adapter is Program_Lure_list_Adapter and the activity that has the code I want to trigger is Activity_program_lure

Comment: then that line should be Activity_program_lure sct = (Activity_program_lure)activity;

Comment: Yes, I have that but activity at the end is unresolved.

Comment: ok do this; take a variable private activity in your adapter class; then modify your public 'Program_Lure_list_Adapter(Activity a, ArrayList<Program_Lure_Sound> result) {
    programLureList = result;
    l_inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
activity =a;
}'</br> and the point where you are calling your custom adapter instead of context pass Activity_program_lure.this; it may be confusing but try to understand that you need to pass your main activity to ur custom adapter then use it here

Comment: Hmmm...I need to pass the activity but the adapter is set as mAdapter and its called like this: mAdapter = new Program_Lure_list_Adapter(this, plsList); </br> activeSoundList.setAdapter(mAdapter);

Comment: activity is still not resolving, I placed it in the Program_Lure_list_Adapter class

Comment: private activity;    
    public Program_Lure_list_Adapter(Activity a, ArrayList<Program_Lure_Sound> result) {
    activity= a;
            programLureList = result;
            l_inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.
                    getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        }

Comment: check the updated answer; sorry for the trouble i m bit sleepy

Comment: I changed it to that and it ran but the onclick is still not triggering. I updated the code above with your changes so you can see.

Comment: then i don't see anything else to help you bro.

Comment: Thanks for all the help

Comment: Could it be because the adapter is View.OnClickListener? So the view is taking it away?

Answer (score 0):

the click event is consumption by view,so has no click event to trigger itemclick .

you can move itemclick code  inside of onclicklistener